# Save data into a new record before deleting/Creating/Updating

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

I need a quick confirmation with my code. The requirement is like this.

1. When I delete/create/update an `Account`.
2. There is this object called `track`.
3. I want this object to have the `Account Name` with `type`.

Here is my code.

```
trigger TrackMethod on Account (before delete) {
    List<Track__c> tList = new List<Track__c>();
    if(Trigger.isBefore)
    { 
        if(Trigger.isDelete){
            for (Account m : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Account where Id IN :Trigger.old]) {
                Track__c t = new Track__c();
                t.Name=m.name;
                t.action__c='Deleted';
                t.type__c='Account';
                tList.add(t);
            }
        }
    }
else if(Trigger.isAfter) {
        for(Account m:trigger.New){
            Track__c t = new Track__c();
            t.Name=m.name;
            if(Trigger.isInsert){
                t.action='Created';
            } else if(Trigger.isUpdate){
                t.action='Updated';
            }
            t.type__c='Method';
            tList.add(t);
        }
    }
    insert tList;
}
```

Please let me know if my code is correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trigger should use after trigger events only, as you're creating related records. No need to use `before delete` when `after delete` would suffice.

Your trigger signature needs to include all possible DML operations you're checking for:

```
trigger TrackMethod on Account (after delete, after insert, after update) {
```

The query in the delete operation isn't necessary, just use records from `Trigger.old`.

Consider using a switch statement, it's easier to read.

Not sure if you meant to say `Type__c='Method'` when the other says Account, so I've accounted for that here.

---

```
trigger TrackMethod on Account (after delete, after insert, after update) {
    Track__c[] trackers = new Track__c[0];
    for(Account record: Trigger.isDelete?Trigger.old:Trigger.new) {
        switch on Trigger.operationType {
            when AFTER_DELETE {
                trackers.add(new Track__c(Name=record.Name, Action__c='Deleted', Type__c='Account'));
            }
            when AFTER_INSERT {
                trackers.add(new Track__c(Name=record.Name, Action__c='Created', Type__c='Account'));
            }
            when AFTER_UPDATE {
                trackers.add(new Track__c(Name=record.Name, Action__c='Updated', Type__c='Account'));
            }
        }
    }
    insert trackers;
}
```

Comment: Hey brother. Thanks for this. It's working as expected. 1 question though, is `Trigger.old` a single record or a list? And an update, there is no `Trigger.operation` anymore. it is `Trigger.operationType`. Thanks again! :-)

Comment: @user3872094 No, `Trigger.operation` was a typo, it's always been `Trigger.operationType`. `Trigger.old` and `Trigger.new` are both `List<sObject>` (typed to the trigger's sObject, such as Account or MyCustomObject__c.